# emacs mimics for some of the most usable vim command

Tags: vim, emacs

i've found emacs extremely powerful and vim very convenient in navigation
but i am not so adapted to vim's model editing idea.
so i sticked to emacs
but i still want to mimic some of the navigation commands in vim
e.g., here is the commands that emacs does not have but. 
note: WORD means word by space or delimiters ")", "\")

```
copy (not kill) region
copy (not kill) rectangle

copy/kill word/WORD forward/backward 

capitalize the head_char/word/WORD/region
```

these can be done in vim so easily by ciw, diw, caw, daw, c(w ....
rather than writing myself, i just wonder if there has available scripts that i can copy and paste to my own init.el?? i dont mind to stretch my pinky anyway..
thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is viper, `M-x viper-mode`. It gives you full vi-style navigation in emacs.

Comment: i dont want the model edit feature.... viper-mode is virtually vim...

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer VIM navigation then check out Evil: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil